# Synonym request: 3rd-party-modules => extensions (mod action required)

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [extensions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extensions) already has a synonym [third-party-module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/third-party-module) and I tried to add [3rd-party-modules](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party-modules) as well.

Unfortunately this results in an error message:

> Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

because StackExchange recognizes the tag as a version specific tag (which is obviously wrong).

Can one of the mods take care of it? IMHO the tags are 100% synonyms.

Comment: Done. Check it if it's done as you expected it.

Comment: Thanks @Marius. I don't see the synonym for "extensions" anymore, was that intentional?

Comment: I merged the `third-..` and `3rd-...` tags. I don't think they are synonyms with `extensions` since 3rd party means the code is not from the core or my own, but from someone else. And the tag `extensions` can be used for questions regarding MY code also

Comment: OK, makes sense, as an extension developer. Thanks for clarifying.